# Flutter \n\n not breaking lines unless hard-coded string

Tags: flutter, line-breaks

I can see that Flutter allows me to use "\n\n" in a string and it causes a line break to appear in a `Text` item:

```
final String answer = "This is my text.\n\n"
    "Here is the 2nd line.";
```

> This is my text.
>
> Here is the 2nd line.

However, when I try to use content pulled from firebase, and set in a variable, the line break ("\n") is actually printed:

```
final String answer = faq['answer'];
```

Shows:

> This is my text.\n\nHere is the 2nd line.

How can I get my "\n\n" to actually show up as line breaks?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support any escape sequences within string values. If you write "\n" in a string, you're going to get exactly that back when you read it.

So you can try something like this:

```
final String answer = (faq['answer'] as String).replaceAll("\\n", "\n");
```